# How does gmail preserve copy and pasted web content, maintaining the attached CSS?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web, gmail

I'm not sure how long the feature has been active, but I've just realized that I can copy and paste nearly any web content into a message on gmail and it will preserve it perfectly-- zero transcription errors. The images, formatting, and all-around CSS are perfectly preserved.

Yet if you paste the same thing into a textbox, of course it gets converted to some sort of plaintext.

I'm trying to figure out how this is possible. How can gmail know the styling for the web content? How can it know where it came from?

This is happening in Chrome, by the way. I don't even know if this is a feature of the browser, the email provider, or a combination thereof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a combination of OS, the source application from which you are copying, and the destination application to which you are pasting.

The source application should permit selection and copying of rich information.

The OS cut/paste functionality needs to understand what the rich content is.

The destination application needs to understand what the rich content is and how to handle it.

When you cut paste HTML page information, CSS is not copy pasted. The information displayed on the screen is copied as rich content and then pasted onto destination system.

Gmail 'understands' how to interpret, correctly, the information pasted into it. A text program also understand how to interpret the information - it knows that it should discard e.g. all images.

MS Word e.g. makes copious mistakes while pasting HTML content. It does not understand, well, how to understand HTML.

Comment: For the sake of clarity: OS clipboard APIs can transfer data in a variety of "flavours": plain text, rich text, HTML, audio. (On Windows and OS X, you can actually specify any data format you wish.) So it's not necessarily that a plain text editor reading the clipboard can understand rich text and strip out images etc. from it, but that the software writing to the clipboard will provide several representations of the what you're copying. (Which makes more sense: the browser is more suited to figuring out how to convert HTML to plain text than a text editor.)

Comment: Analogously, when you're copy pasting from a web browser into another tab of the same web browser, it's entirely possible the browser is writing HTML into the clipboard instead of doing a round-trip through rich text. (I'd also argue it's more likely, since the browser already knows what style declarations are applied to any given element, so emitting a canonical representation should be simple.) Chrome certainly does offer a HTML flavour of anything you copy.

Comment: I guess the question I still have then, is how does gmail "understand" how to interpret rich information? How is that done with JavaScript? What API is there for that?